# Does geminal dibromide reacts with sodamide to form internal alkyne or terminal alkyne?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am currently studying the topic of synthesizing alkenes from double dehydrohalogenation of vicinal and geminal dihalides.

[image]

This is a reaction problem I got from an organic tutor on YouTube and he was explaining how $\ce{NaNH2}$ will favor the production of terminal alkynes on the contrary to $\ce{KOH}$ that will favor internal alkynes. He didn't go into the mechanism  for this one but drew the product only which will be 1-butyne.

I wanted to understand the mechanism behind it but couldn't find an exact problem on internet. Could someone please explain to me what is the mechanism and why can it not favor the internal part of the chain as it produces a more stable alkyne ?

Comment: Welcome to chem.SE. I have edited the question. Make sure to give proper punctuation and capitalization.

Comment: oooh i see. so it depends if its occurring at high temperature or low temperature right?